# C: Why I can't pass a string literal as a function argument?

Tags: c, string

I thought I could pass a string pointer to a function as such:

```
int main() 
{
   const char fileName[] = "network/fileName.yo";
   WriteFile(fileName);
}

int WriteNetwork(char* fileName)
{
   printf("the filename is %s\n", fileName);
}
```

but this doesn't seem to work as I expect it. I must be missing something very simple, but can't seem to track it down!

Comment: `WriteFile` or `WriteNetwork`?

Comment: How did it work? How did you expect it to work? What happened? These are things that are useful to include.

Comment: change the `WriteFile` declaration to take a `const char*`

Comment: `char* fileName` --> `const char* fileName`

Comment: To elaborate on *why* you need to change WriteNetwork() to take a const pointer:  when you declared filename[] as *const*, you made a promise not to allow anything to change the contents of that array.  Since WriteNetwork() (in the snippet shown) takes a non-const pointer, that means WriteNetwork() could (if it wanted to) change the data its argument pointed to, which would break your promise.  So the compiler won't allow you to pass that argument to WriteNetwork().  By changing WriteNetwork() to take a const-pointer, WriteNetwork() now also promises not to change that data.

Comment: "method" in C is a "function"

Comment: What a chameleon this is? Who *upvoted* this? There is still no error message, I've voted to close this. There is a `const error`, no return value specified, wrong function name, implicit function definition x 2 / no header included for `printf` and not a single hint towards the actual error message.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Hmmm. You're right. This question should contain a question about an error message which the OP is confused about, so that we can clarify that error message for the OP, thus making the problem more easily found by future users.

Answer (score 6):

The pointer to the string literal is not being passed to `WriteFile()`.  `fileName[]` is initialized with the string literal `"network/fileName.yo"`.  It is the variable `fileName` that is passed.  As it is an array, it is converted into a pointer to its first element..

Declare or define `WriteNetwork()` before using it.

Passing a pointer to `const` data to a function expecting a pointer to non-`const` data should fail to compile. Change `WriteNetwork()` to accept a `const` pointer. [@Lưu Vĩnh Phúc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46045852/c-why-cant-i-pass-a-string-literal-as-a-method-argument/46046131#comment79051603_46045852)

Also note the post seems to treat `WriteFile()` as `WriteNetwork()` [@Ray Toal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46045852/c-why-i-cant-pass-a-string-literal-as-a-function-argument/46046131#comment79051578_46045852).  Certainly this is a clerical error and the function name and call should be the same.

```
// int WriteNetwork(const char* fileName) {
int WriteFile(const char* fileName) {
   printf("the filename is %s\n", fileName);
}

int main(void) { 
  const char fileName[] = "network/fileName.yo";
  WriteFile(fileName);
}
```

---

> i must be missing something very simple but can't seem to track it down!

Tip: 
Save time.  Enable all compiler warnings.  They provide quick feedback to help you "track it down".

Comment: Great! This answer *could* be better still, if you were to introduce forward declaration, but since there's more than one way to skin a cat this 1/ answers the question and 2/ is accurate, so... my heart can do the love emoji!